# Trouble running GWT 2.7 net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin project

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode, gwt-maven-plugin

I feel like this might be a dumb question and the answer is probably very simple. I am using Eclipse 4.4 and Maven to run my GWT 2.7 app. I am in the process of redesigning my project layout and wanted to use the new gwt-maven-plugin by @ThomasBroyer.

I create a new maven project from archetype modular-webapp in eclipse as directed in the readme [here](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes) The next part I am a little unsure of, but with the parent project I right click-> Run As->Maven Build and set the goal to "gwt:codeserver -pl *-client -am", it starts the code server on http://localhost:9876/. So that is good. The next thing I think I am suppose to do is run the jetty for server code so I right click on the *-server project->Run As->Maven Build and set the goal to "jetty:start -Denv=dev", it says build complete and the jetty is started but if I go to localhost:8888/index.html says it can't be found. I am sure that I am overlooking something very obvious, but some direction would be most helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `project->Run As->Maven Build("gwt-run")`? The code server should just start itself and the code will compile when you go to localhost:8888

Comment: @slugmandrew - I tried as you suggested but got this: Unknown lifecycle phase "gwt-run". Are you talking about the org.codehaus.mojo gwt-maven-plugin because I am trying to work with the net.ltgt.gwt.archetypes plugin as previously mentioned and linked to.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I hadn't seen the new plugin at the time. When you said "new plugin by @ThomasBroyer" I assumed you meant the 2.7.0 one over the 2.6.0 :/ Sorry! Did you find an answer in the end? I had a look at that new plugin and it looks a bit complicated to set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come to a solution thanks to help on the gwt google groups forum. Basically I was able to run it using tomcat, never got the jetty to work. See the link here https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/SVM-0hedJEQ

Comment: I understand that You make GWT 2.7.0 to work with maven and eclipse? I struggle with that to. Can I ask You more questions on chat?

Comment: Sure but check out the google groups forum, it has many answers as well. @masterdany88